# Сохранить прогресс аудио-файла

Tags: c#, аудио

как сохранить прогресс аудио-файла. Сделал кнопку перевёртыш, надо что бы после "стоп" продолжала играть с того места где остановилось

```
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    bool playeORstop = true;
    private void buttonWav_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if(fileName == string.Empty) { return; }

        if (playeORstop){
            buttonWav.BackgroundImage = Resources.stop;
            playeORstop = !playeORstop;
        }else{
            buttonWav.BackgroundImage = Resources.playe;
            player.Stop();
            playeORstop = !playeORstop;
            return;
        }

        try{
            player.SoundLocation = fileName;
            player.Play();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show($"{ex.Message}", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            OpenMedia();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `SoundPlayer`, который вы скорей всего используете, не предназначен для подобных задач. Его цель, это просто проиграть небольшой звук, не более.

Comment: что надо использовать? предполагается крохотное приложение для прослушивания ауди-книг

Comment: Есть мощная библиотека для работы со звуками - [NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/), попробуйте её.

Comment: Стандартных механизмов, под WinForms, на сколько я знаю, нет. Так что ищите сторонние альтернативы, их благо полно.

Answer (score 0):

можешь попробовать использовать [WindowsMediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/creating-the-windows-media-player-control-programmatically?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

это можеть быть полезным: [How to use WMPLib in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29126878/4423545)

```
WindowsMediaPlayer myplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();

myplayer.URL = @"C:\song.mp3";


myplayer.controls.play();

myplayer.controls.stop();

myplayer.controls.pause();
```